# Jmeter View Results Tree doesn't return anything in Response Data

Tags: api, testing, jmeter, response

I sent a HTTP request. There is an error in View Results Tree. But In the Response Data doesn't seem anything.

How can I see the error logs?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is that page[Audit-getaudits] require any authentication to access? I mean in your site if want to access that page , does it ask for login?

Comment: Yes, there is an authentication to access. But I already pass it at the beginning. The method works for 20 users. But It gives %70 errors for 30 users. I want to see the error logs why.

Comment: click the sampler result tab. what does it say there? You can view the jmeter log by clicking the exclamation mark in a yellow triangle at the top right of the GUI, but it's probably not what you really want. It appears the server gave an error so there was no response body/data. check the error in sampler result tab.

Comment: I added a capture of sampler result. I am waiting for 200 as response code. But that returns 202. And there are no error on yellow triangle :(

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't use JMeter GUI to run performance tests. Run test [in command-line non-GUI mode](http://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) instead.
2. Don't use View Results Tree listener for anything but tests development or single-threaded debugging, it's too memory intensive and basically stores all requests/responses details in the memory. It might be the cause of errors you're getting. As per [documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)

> View Results Tree MUST NOT BE USED during load test as it consumes a lot of resources (memory and CPU). Use it only for either functional testing or during Test Plan debugging and Validation.

3. If you need to store response data on error in .jtl results file add the following line to *user.properties* file (it usually lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true
   ```
4. Alternatively you can use a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to capture full requests/responses details for later inspection.

Comment: Great info. you have shared. But how can we get more expanded result like view result tree provide. Because when run test using NON-GUI command line , it shows very few fields to analyze result..

Comment: You can configure what is stored in .jtl results file via changing other `jmeter.save.saveservice` properties (look into *jmeter.properties* file for a full list. Keep in mind that any extra bit of information has impact on JMeter performance so you can use verbose logging for debug purposes and revert back to defaults for real test. See http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization guide for information on how properties can be set or changed.